# Content do not appear on Chrome but do on Safari

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know if it is the right place to post my question, please redirect me if necessary.

Here is my problem: I try to access this webpage : http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/people/t.wiseman/teaching

From Chrome, I get this view. 
[image: from Chrome]

While from Safari, I can access the whole page. 
[image: from Safari]

I was wondering if it was due to some extensions, as Ad-Block, but no, it is not the case. Can anyone help me? I sincerely have no clue of what's happening.

Comment: Chrome works for me. Disable your plugins and make sure you update your browser to the latest version

Comment: Browser up to date, plugins disabled... Still not working. And I have the same issue using Chrome on the university computers.